# PySide6: How to change the QLabel color dynamically without changing other style

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I am learning PySide6 and trying to build a clock. I want to dynamically change the label color, how can I make it? The following is parts of my codes.

```py
class Clock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(1100, 800, 180, 60)

        # Mouse & Menu
        self.pressed = False
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.mouseRightMenu)

        self.clock = QTimer(self)
        self.clock.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.clock.start(1000)

        self.settings = QSettings(f"{sys.argv[0]}/../config.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(int(self.settings.value("USER/FONT_SIZE")))
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFont(font)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"color: {self.settings.value('USER/FONT_COLOR')}")

    def mouseRightMenu(self, pos):
        menu = QMenu(self)

        colors = ["black", "red", "yellow", "blue", "orange", "green", "white"]

        # font color
        font_color_menu = menu.addMenu("font color")
        font_color_actions = [QAction(color, self) for color in colors]

        for action, color in zip(font_color_actions, colors):
            action.triggered.connect(lambda c=color: self.setFontColor(c))
            font_color_menu.addAction(action)

        # background color
        bg_color_menu = menu.addMenu("bg color")
        bg_color_actions = [QAction(color, self) for color in colors]

        for action, color in zip(bg_color_actions, colors):
            action.triggered.connect(lambda color: self.setBackgroundColor(color))
            bg_color_menu.addAction(action)

        menu.exec(self.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def setFontColor(self, color: str):
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f"color: {color}")

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QTime.currentTime().toString("hh:mm")
        self.label.setText(current_time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Clock()
    clock.show()  # show all the widgets
    app.exit(app.exec())  # start the app
```

The `QAction` in `mouseRightMenu` function not works. Besides, I cannot change the font color with changing the background color.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Always check the arguments when creating lambdas: the first argument of the [`triggered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaction.html#triggered) signal is the check state. Change to `lambda _, color=color: ...`.

Comment: Changed to `font_color_actions = [QAction(color, self, triggered=lambda color=color: self.setFontColor(color)) for color in colors]` with help of ChatGPT  Thank you all the same!

Comment: Which is conceptually the same as you wrote above. With an important difference: ChatGPT, as a wonderful tool as it is, is **not** capable of properly distinguish proper context and code (at least, yet). It may provide interesting insight, which, interestingly enough, is based on existing experience (including what I wrote above and in my previous interactions). That's it: it's *interesting insight*, and, while *possibly* useful, it's why ChatGPT based answers are now banned on SO. Not because we're "afraid" of AI (on the contrary), but because we're aware of its current capabilities. Are you?

Comment: For instance, I can't test right now, but I know PySide behaves slightly differently from PyQt for signal connections. The code you wrote above will **never** work properly there, as the `checked` arg is considered positional. I sincerely doubt it should in PySide either (there's known inconsistency with partials, not lambdas). And ChatGPT isn't able to tell you that difference, you have to *know* it from experience. So: AI is a wonderful achievement, but not yet ready for this, **especially** for learning purposes. You want to learn? Be patient, study. AI is a resource, not the answer. Yet.

Comment: I agree with your opinion about AI. In fact, I clearly knew that there is a serious problem in the lambda part. I tried to fix it in some ways, then it became kinda annoying—because it should not be a big obstacle in my knowledge. To a large extent, I tried ChatGPT for self-confidence. I am a beginner in GUI programming, and I don't have much time for this. At an early stage, it can be more comfortable for me to learn `PySide6`  from experience.

Comment: I appreciate your time and patience to share your view on **ChatGPT** and attitude towards learning. “How to get help from AI appropriately” is well worth continuous discussion, while I'm exploring this newborn tech, I am also trying to balance its power and drawbacks.